# what is the integration technique to integrate the following function?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

What is the integral of the given trigonometric function?

$$\int\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(\alpha)\cos(x)}dx$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html

Comment: i would try the $\tan(x/2)$ substitution

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I could never keep this substitution in mind, but now that I know it is named Weierstrass Substitution it will be easier to remember. Thank you!

Comment: Good old trig books did not mention Weierstrass name, thats why!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** with $\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and $\cos\alpha=k$ we see
$$\int\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(\alpha)\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{2}{-k}\frac{e^{ix}}{(e^{ix}-\frac1k)^2+(1-\frac{1}{k^2})}dx$$
and using substituation 
$$e^{ix}-\frac1k=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^2}}\tan\theta$$
we can finish solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int{\dd x \over 1 - \cos\pars{\alpha}\cos\pars{x}} =
\int{\dd x \over 1 - \cos\pars{\alpha}\bracks{2\cos^{2}\pars{x/2} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int{\dd x \over 1 + \cos\pars{\alpha} - 2\cos\pars{\alpha}\cos^{2}\pars{x/2}} =
\int{\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} \over
\bracks{1 + \cos\pars{\alpha}}\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} - 2\cos\pars{\alpha}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int{\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} \over
\bracks{1 + \cos\pars{\alpha}}\tan^{2}\pars{x/2} + 1 - \cos\pars{\alpha}}\,\dd x =
\int{\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} \over
2\cos^{2}\pars{\alpha/2}\tan^{2}\pars{x/2} + 2\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha/2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha/2}}\,\tan\pars{\alpha \over 2}
\int{\cot\pars{\alpha/2}\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} \over
\bracks{\cot\pars{\alpha/2}\tan\pars{x/2}}^{\,2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{{2 \over \sin\pars{\alpha}}\,
\arctan\pars{\cot\pars{\alpha \over 2}\tan\pars{x \over 2}} +
\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}}}
 \end{align}